# Finding info (manufacturer, card type...) about a ISO-14443 card with PCSC reader

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, mifare, pcsc

I recently began to use a PCSC reader with ISO-14443 cards.
I'm just looking for a way to tell what type of card has been inserted in my reader.
Is there a specific command that I could use ?
For example, how can I tell if a MIFARE DESFire card has been inserted ?
I'm using java, with a ACR122U reader.
Thanks !

Comment: You can read ACR122U manual about specific commands and so on. 
https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.04.pdf

Comment: @nvf Yeah, I did read it, but the only method I found are about reading UID and ATS, which (I thibk) do not help me. Does that mean there is no way I can do it ?

Comment: I can guess you can understand card type by ATR. Refer to "3.1. ATR Generation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO 14443-cards cover such a wide spectrum, that this is is extremely dependent on what you have. UID may be randomized, and so does not help. If the reader does not provide some diagnostics, see commented manual, you are on your own.

In practical applications this is no issue; the approach "Give me whatever card you like and I'll do something with it" rarely occurs, since recognition of the card type is by miles insufficient to handle a card, which requires authentication.